# Counting numbers in an array based on a criteria - python

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a numpy two-dimensional array from a time series x, which actually represents the coordinates of points in a 2d coordinate system.

```
#two dimensional array
xy=[x11,x12]
```

How can I count the numbers of points which lie in the quadrants of the coordinate system?
For example, if a point lies in the first quadrants

```
x11>0 & x12>0
```

Also, how can I count the number of points which lie above the line x11==x12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First quadrant: `sum((xy[0] > 0) & (xy[1] > 0))`. 
Second quadrant: `sum((xy[0] < 0) & (xy[1] > 0))`. Etc.

Above the line: `sum(xy[1] > xy[0])` (y>x).

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do it that way previously, but I got an error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1363,) (1362,) "

Comment: One of your arrays is longer than the other by 1. Make sure that `x11` and `x12` have the same length. Also, `[x11,x12]` does not make a 2d array. Use `np.array([x11,x12])`.

Comment: What a fail. I did the correction later, but did the code without it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you mean?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [[1,3], [2,2], [5,2], [11,11]]
>>> data = np.array(data)
>>> data
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 2,  2],
       [ 5,  2],
       [11, 11]])
>>> [x for x in data if x[0] == x[1]]
[array([2, 2]), array([11, 11])]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the data is a one dimensional array, which I converted into a two dimensional, that is not structured as data in your example. More like two columns of numbers. Is there a simple way to make pairs of it?